# Paramiko ssh/ sftp multiple commands

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to achieve some automation with python and paramiko (with my basic beginner logic).

The code below I'm happy to say works. Until I add in the command 'rm -f testtrace.pcap to delete the file once it has been downloaded via sftp.

## Define login credentials

```
host = input("Host: ")
user = input("User: ")
port = 22
password = getpass("Password: ")
```

## Open ssh connection

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port=port, username=user, password=password)
```

## Execute command run tcpdump

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('timeout 10 tcpdump port 5060 -nnv -s 0 -w testtrace.pcap')
channel = stdout.channel
channel.recv_exit_status()
ssh.close()
```

## Open sftp connection

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username=user, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

## File Download

```
filepath = '/root/testtrace.pcap'
localpath = 'C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\python\\testtrace.pcap'
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
```

## Execute command delete file

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('rm -f testtrace.pcap')
channel = stdout.channel
channel.recv_exit_status()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Right so a problem that I've been struggling with for a day or two, I've manage to solve within 10 minute of signing up to Stackoverflow!.

Answer (score 0):

Right so a problem that I've been struggling with for a day or two, I've manage to solve within 10 minute of signing up to Stackoverflow!.

## Execute command run tcpdump

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('timeout 10 tcpdump port 5060 -nnv -s 0 -w testtrace.pcap')
channel = stdout.channel
channel.recv_exit_status()
```

I was closing the ssh connection too early. By removing ssh.close() from this section it appears to have solved the issue and now functions correctly.